# How do I properly attach to the keypress event?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, keypress

I have a seemingly simple problem to which I can't find a solution. Given the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.onkeypress = function(ev) {
                if (!ev) { alert("Broken"); return; }
                var key = ev.charCode || ev.keyCode;
                alert(key);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>Test</body>
</html>
```

If I save it as a file and load it in IE and I press a key it always comes up with the "Broken" alert whereas it works fine (alert with the keycode) in Firefox.

If I use `window.onkeypress` instead of the document handler it's not being called at all in IE. If I attach the handler in the `onload` event it doesn't make a difference. Using events like `keydown` or `keyup` don't make a difference (still broken in IE).

Yet, when I use [jsfiddle for the example](http://jsfiddle.net/m38M6/) it works fine in IE.

So: What does jsfiddle differently from the code above and how do I get it to work in IE?

Comment: The difference between your code and the fiddle is that it puts your code in `window.onload`. Just saying. Also, where's your DOCTYPE? You should have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the very top as the first line. Also, you shouldn't need to check for `ev`. Just use `ev = ev || window.event;` as the first line of your function (take out the `if` line).

Comment: Not sure if it's the issue, but the `DOCTYPE` is especially important in IE; otherwise IE renders in "quirks mode."

Comment: Ok, that's it, the DOCTYPE was missing. I can't believe that IE breaks in such non-obvious subtle way (especially since the actual code has a lots more javascript embedded in the page which work just fine)

Comment: @Ian: If you post this as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including a DOCTYPE is important in any browser, but even more in IE. If one is omitted, I believe it uses quirks mode, which means bad things. You can add the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Doctypes should be the first non-empty line in an HTML file. That means even comments shouldn't come before the doctype, and can cause IE to use quirks mode.

Here is a nice little read on the difference between standards mode and quirks mode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode

In addition, as a note, IE uses the global `event` variable for events, so you should check that instead of thinking it's broken. For example:

```
ev = ev || window.event;
```

can replace your `if` statement line.

Answer (score 3):

IE doesn't pass the event object to your event handler; instead it's available in window.event. In IE when using addEventListener or attachEvent "this" in the event listener will refer to window instead of the element that the event came from and was attached/added on.

```
        document.onkeypress = function(ev) {
            ev = window.event||ev;
            var key = ev.charCode || ev.keyCode;
            alert(key);
        }
```

Comment: This seems to work as well. Should probably be done both: Adding DOCTYPE and using window.event

Comment: The statement "In IE the "this" context is window" is not correct in this case, you are thinking of *attachEvent*. Where listeners are added as a DOM property, *this* will reference the element in all browsers. Also, in ES5 the term "context" is only used in regard to [execution context](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10). A function's *this* is only one part of that context and can be set to any object (or any value in strict mode) by the call.

Comment: @RobG yes, you are correct. If you want to attach multiple handlers you can't use Element.onSomething but have to use attachEvent or addEventListener

Comment: @ChrisWue it's important to add doctype, in firefox pages render differently when it's not defined; for example if you omit the px for size values. Any browser goes into quirks mode because without doc type the html is not valid html and the browser will correct it for you.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery also helps with some of these cross browser issues, here it is with jQuery:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
      alert(e.keyCode);
});
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/eFAaF/)